# Lubuntu wifi connection issues

Tags: wireless, lubuntu

I recently acquired an older computer running Lubuntu (I will update with more specific information as requested). The PC does not have a wireless adapter, and so I bought a USB wifi adapter (Kootek USB 2.0 802.IIN).

I think the drivers installed correctly (they auto installed) because I can now see all the networks in my office. However whenever I try to connect to any of the networks, it tries for a bit and then gives up. What are the standard things to try in this situation?

`lsusb` result:

```
Bus 001 Device 002: ID 0bda:8176 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188CUS 802.11n WLAN Adapter
BUS001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
```

There are some more like the second line too.

Update:
I took the computer home over the weekend and managed to get it all working there. In particular I followed https://sites.google.com/site/easylinuxtipsproject/reserve-7 . When I got it to work today though, I can't see any of the local networks, but I can teather it to my phone. Very strange.

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command.

Comment: @Pilot6 Done, thank you for your help.

Comment: You need to install a driver for this adapter. Search this site by `RTL8188CUS`

Comment: @Pilot6 Thanks again. Unfortunately all the solutions begin "using a temporary internet connection..." I'll try again next week.

Comment: It is possible to do it without a connection, but it is a bit harder to explain.

Comment: No doubt. I can't even get the drivers on the cd that came with the chip to install so I probably shouldn't be trying to compile things from source.

Comment: The drivers from CD most likely won't build.